# Expand InsideView By Default In SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

By default, InsideView sub panel in Accounts module is collapsed in SugarCRM. How can I make it expanded by default? To be more clear, when any Account is opened, by default the Inside View subpanel present within it should be expanded.

Since I am new to SugarCRM, please provide me the complete steps.

Comment: I don't think there's an out-of-box way to open it by default for all users, but Sugar will "remember" that each user has/has not opened the Inside View panel.

Comment: When I expand the Inside View and refresh the browser page or login again, still by default Inside view is collapsed. Can you please explain me how does sugar remember that?